# capturing the login event in zendframework 2

Tags: event-handling, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I want to capture the **loggin event** in zendframework2 and then update the database when the  user last logged in.

i am aware that if i do the following in the **onBootstrap(MVCEvent $e)** of my module i will be able to capture the event etc:

```
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
            $em           = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
            $em->attach(
                'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain',
                'authenticate',
                function($e)
                {
                    $id = $e->getIdentity();

   }
            );
```

this will give me the **Id of the user**. however, the confusion is how i can then update my database from the bootstrap. i mean, i dont have access to the **entity manager** in my bootstrap and i am not sure how to transport it there. the entity manager is held in the service config file.

i.e 
     getServiceConfig()

```
'Members\Model\WorkerTable' => function($sm) {
                    $db = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                    $table = new Model\MemberTable($db);
                    return $table;
                },
```

.

with the above settings i am able to access the entity manager in my **MemberTable class**

so, a simple solution would be to transfer the **loggin event manager** to my 
** MemberTable class** where i would use my entity manager to update the database.

issue,  i am not sure how to set this up:

```
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
                $em           = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
```

i mean, i dont know how to get the variable $e into the **MemberTable class** so that i can access the **eventManger** and the sharedManager.

in summary; the issues are twofold.

1. how do i get the entity manager into the bootstrap function

alternatively

2. how do i get the eventManager and shared eventmanager into a normal class so that i can call the eventmanger in a class that already contains the entity manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all you have to do is to retrieve the service manager this way:

```
$serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
```

and then get your entity manager like this:

```
$entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Members\Model\WorkerTable');
```

Does it solve your problem?

**The answer to the second question**

To bring a variable into the closure from outside you can use "**use**" operator like so:

```
function() use ($myVar){
    // some code
}
```

So, in your case I would do:

```
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $em = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $em->attach(
            'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain',
            'authenticate',
            function($e) use ($entityManager){
                $id = $e->getIdentity();

            }
        );
```

If you are planning to have a lot of code inside your closure I would suggest to put it into a separate class and make it invokable. For instance,

```
class YourClosureCode
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct($eventManager)
    {
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
    }

    public function __invoke(EventInterface $e)
    {
       // put your closure code here
    }
}
```

Then a slight modification here:

```
 $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $em = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $em->attach(
            'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain',
            'authenticate',
            new YourClosureCode($entityManager);
        );
```

Comment: hi Next Developer. great idea. thank u. it helps me to get teh entity manager into the bootstap. but how then do i get the entity manger into the closure. i have updated my question to show the problem

Comment: ah. i understand. let me try it straighty away.thanks Next Developer tanks

Comment: hey Next Developer. thanks so much for your help. It worked perfectly.